# Force simulation issue porting Radviz to D3V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm porting a Radviz visualization from D3.V3 (Originally from Biovisualize) to D3.V4, and I am having issues with the new force simulation model.
   The new model is almost identical in the end result...but almost is not enough. Can anyone help me with the conversion?

The original code goes like this:

```
var force = d3.layout.force().chargeDistance(0).charge(-60).friction(.5);
force.size([ panelSize, panelSize ]).linkStrength(function(d) {
    return d.value;        
}).nodes(data.concat(dimensionNodes)).links(linksData).start();
```

The code I'm currently using to setup the simulation is this:

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation(data.concat(dimensionNodes))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(linksData).strength(function(d) { return d.value; }))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(panelSize / 2, panelSize / 2));
```

The remaing code is basically the same as the original from Biovizalize, changing only the commands from V3 to V4, such as scale.ordinal to scaleOrdinal.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ2dT.png) is an image of the resulting problem. On the left is the original Radviz (A1) with a single node selected (a2). To the right the modified Radviz to work with D3.V4 (B1) with the same node selected (B2).

Every node on the modified visualization tend to go up a little when the simulation stabilizes.

Original Radviz code from Biovisualize: http://www.biovisualize.com/2016/03/radviz.html

Comment: Hi @Clausius I was also trying to port radviz to d3 v4. Can you please share your snippets for the v4 port. I am looking to integrate d3 annotations with radviz, so I can submit a pull request for the same if you want

Comment: Sure, will make a bl.ocks example and post here the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time & help.

Comment: otherwise, I was wondering if you have the source handy & can share it with me, I can build the bl.ock & also share the link with you if you need to fork it anytime.